# Ubuntu. Не выполняется "rename" внутри "bash-скрипта" при передаче параметра при запуске

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Помогите пожалуйста советом. Ситуация следующая... Имеется файл **script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

rename 's/(?<=x001x).*/8888888888888888.php/' /var/www/html/*.php
```

Задача этого файла, найти в директории **"/var/www/html/"** все файлы с расширением **.php**. Среди этих файлов определить тот, имя которого начинается с **"x001x"** и изменить текст после символов **"x001x"** на **"8888888888888888.php"**

При запуске файла из консоли в таком формате: `sudo bash script.sh` - все отрабатывает нормально. Но возникла необходимость запускать файл **script.sh** с параметром который будет передан внутрь "конструкции" **rename** для замены части строки **8888888888888888** на данные которые будут переданы "параметром".

В таком формате (часть строки "8888888888888888" заменена на $1) :

```
#!/bin/bash

rename 's/(?<=x001x).*/$1.php/' /var/www/html/*.php
```

Но при запуске: `sudo bash 1change.sh 99999999999`

Получаю ошибку: `Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 4) line 1.`

Я уже пробовал передавать параметр $1 в переменную внутри скрипта, например `VAR=$1` и потом добавлять переменную **$VAR** в скрипт. Пробовал конкатенировать тело скрипта из 3 переменных в одну строку. Но заставить работать конструкцию rename так и не получилось. Есть мнение что это связано с этой реализацией rename регулярное выражение которое реализовано через перл по этому и не получается передать переменную. Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли решение в этой ситуации? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерполяция не работает в единичных кавычках.  Используйте двойные,
либо катенируйте строки.

Comment: Огромное вам человеческое спасибо. Заменил на двойные кавычки и все заработало. В таком формате:
rename "s/(?<=x001x).*/$1.php/" /var/www/html/*.php 
Еще раз спасибо.